# called object is not a function or function pointer in use of ternary

Tags: c, io, ternary-operator, puts

I am constantly receiving:

`error: called object is not a function or function pointer`

When using ternary operator like that:

`puts("\nx: " (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");`

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, don´t pay attention to the content of the line. I just exemplified it. The point is in the syntax, which remains the same as the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to call an object which is neither a function nor a function pointer!  In particular, the compiler is seeing the open paren after the string and thinks (as much as a compiler can be said to "think") that you are trying to invoke a function call.  You cannot concatenate a string with the ternary operator as you are trying to do.  Try:

```
printf("\nx: %s", (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. Well I thought I can, since I can `printf("sample"" continues");` Now the ternary is 1 level more useless to me.

Comment: Two literal strings can indeed be concatenated that way.  That rule does not extend to other tokens.

Comment: @Malina it's not, there is not  much difference between your code and this solution.

Comment: @iharob Technically yes. But there is still difference pro-ternary.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> puts("\nx: " (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");
> ```

This is not the right way to do what you want, because you cannot concatenate C strings like this.

You can do this using `puts()`:

```
puts("\nx: ");
puts((0==1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");
```

#### EDIT: (Suggested by @WilliamPursell

To avoid the appending of an unwanted newline character, use `fputs()` instead of `puts()`.

```
fputs("\nx: ");
fputs((0==1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");
```

Comment: This will insert an additional newline between the `: ` and the `y`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will. Your `printf()` method is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can not concat the strings the way you do.

The simple solution is to use printf

```
printf("\nx: %s", (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n");
```

or if you insist on using puts you need the strcat function from string.h

```
char s[256] = "\nx: ";
puts(strcat(s, (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
"\nx: " (0 == 1) ? "y1\n" : "y2\n"
/*     ^ this is ignored        */
```

so it seems as if the string literal was being called as a function -> `"\nx: "(0 == 1)`, doesn't it look like that?

You can achieve what you want with the `printf()` function like this

```
printf("\nx: %s\n", (0 == 1) ? "y1" : "y2");
```